# Insert into database with unknown number of input type texts php

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Okay so lets say i have an undefined number of selected rows in my database. I used while loop so the input area keeps increasing. 
My question is how do i insert into my database without knowing how many values should be inserted? Should i use some kind of loop?

```
<form method = "POST" action = "save.php">

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

<input type = "text" name="txtname">

}

<input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value = "Save">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases inserting multiple records with one Insert statement is much faster in MySQL than inserting records with for/foreach loop in PHP.

Let's assume $column1 and $column2 are arrays with same size posted by html form.

You can create your query like this:

```
<?php
    $query = 'INSERT INTO TABLE (`column1`, `column2`) VALUES ';
    $query_parts = array();
    for($x=0; $x<count($column1); $x++){
        $query_parts[] = "('" . $column1[$x] . "', '" . $column2[$x] . "')";
    }
    echo $query .= implode(',', $query_parts);
?>
```

If data is posted for two records the query will become:

> INSERT INTO TABLE (column1, column2) VALUES ('data', 'data'), ('data',
>   'data')

Comment: what should i substitute for "$column1" ? the name of the input type?
for($x=0; $x<count($column1); $x++){

Comment: yes there will be multiple values so $column1 will be replacing with the input type value variable

Comment: This desperately requires proper SQL escaping. You can't just chuck stuff in the query and think the quotes are good enough.